# jquery mobile make a phone call when pressing a button

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm building a mobile website using HTML 5 and CSS with Query mobile

I have a button like this

```
<a data-role="button" data-icon="grid" >Contact me for a meeting</a>
```

I would like add an "action" so when a user click he can call a phone number.

Please note the application is running in the browser, I would like to know if there is a build in function in query or other solution. Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that a lot of people don't like calling because it is too confronting. Provide the option for an email or a text message!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look here - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/docs/pages/link-formats.html

I think the `tel:` protocol will do it for you

Comment: `tel: attribute` -> `tel: protocol`