# How to make a phone call via jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile

How to make a phone call via jquery mobile.

here is the code which iam trying.but it is not functioning both emulator and the real device.

```
  <li><a href="#"  "tel:012345678">Call</a></li>
```

please help.

Comment: `href="tel:012345667"`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery mobile make a phone call when pressing a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647513/jquery-mobile-make-a-phone-call-when-pressing-a-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<li><a href="tel:+012345678">Call</a></li>
```